# Uploadify Preventing Future Ajax Requests

Tags: php, jquery, session, uploadify

I'm attempting to use Uploadify for Ajax file requests. However, I have come across a very odd situation. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: "choice="+choice,
    url: "getformdata.php",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {

        $(".file-upload").each(function() {
            var $p = $(this).parent();
            $(this).uploadify({
                'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': 'uploadify.php',
                'fileTypeDesc': '.doc, .docx, or .pdf',
                'fileTypeExts' : '*.doc; *.docx; *.pdf',
                'onUploadError' : function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                    alert('The file ' + file.name + ' could not be uploaded: ' + errorString);
                },
                'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                    $($p).find("input[type='hidden']").val(data);
                    $($p).find(".file-name span").text(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

As it is currently, if I attempt to make another Ajax request, PHP somehow does not know about any of my session variables. As soon as I take out the .uploadify() method, it suddenly knows about my session variables again.

What exactly causes this? Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

With the code you posted, you are doing 2 requests, one on the file getformdata.php and the other on the file uploadify.php, the second is the one packaged with uploadify ... it does not use session_start() ... so i think that your PHPSESSID is changed ... 
 Regards

mimiz

Comment: I called session_id() in both and it appears to be the same, I'll try adding session_start() to uploadify, though.

Comment: I tried adding a specific session ID to all of my pages except Uploadify, but that does not help. I really do not understand it, because Uploadify does attempt to create a session via PHP at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in uploadify engine. If you look on their site it's happen the same thing. As many times you use the controll, somehow tries to load twice the swf and calls by mistake the folder where your URL is if you know what I mean.